# Why can't an `async def` coroutine function contain any `yield`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From Python in a Nutshell, why is it that

> An `async def`  coroutine function cannot contain any  `yield`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is stated in the rationale of [PEP 492](https://peps.python.org/pep-0492/#id52) which introduced `async`/`await` and forbid the use of `yield` inside them:

> Current Python supports implementing coroutines via generators (PEP
> 342), further enhanced by the yield from syntax introduced in PEP 380.
> This approach has a number of shortcomings:
>
> - It is easy to confuse coroutines with regular generators, since they
>   share the same syntax; this is especially true for new developers.

> - Whether or not a function is a coroutine is determined by a presence
>   of yield or yield from statements in its body, which can lead to
>   unobvious errors when such statements appear in or disappear from
>   function body during refactoring.

> - Support for asynchronous calls is
>   limited to expressions where yield is allowed syntactically, limiting
>   the usefulness of syntactic features, such as with and for statements.

This only applies in Python 3.5

In Python 3.6, [PEP 525](https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/) came along and lifted the ban with asynchronous generators. Now using `yield` inside async def functions results in an asynchronous generator being created.

Comment: Thanks. Does using `yield` inside a `async def` function result in a coroutine? What is the definition of a coroutine?

Comment: A coroutine is a function that can yield values and can accept values during execution from the caller.